# Limit UDP communication to a certain NIC

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I have two identical network devices. Both are hardwired to the IP `192.168.137.128`. Both devices receive UDP packets sent to their IP and respond with UDP broadcast packets sent to `192.168.137.255`. I also have a Linux (Debian) machine with 3 NICs, where `eth0` is configured to have IP `192.168.137.1` and connected to device 1, `eth2` is at `192.168.137.17`m and `eth1` connects to the world. The two identical subnets are not connected.

So the problem is to

- chose the correct NIC to send outgoing packets to `192.168.137.128` depending on the sender IP
- respond to broadcast packets

The best I've managed to do is use `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, which requires me to know the actual NIC device name and more importantly requires me to run the programme as root.

So  apart from this issue, the following programme does what I want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define  sockopt_t int

#define OUTPORT 51001
#define INPORT 51002

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd[2];
    unsigned char buf[1666];
    struct sockaddr_in sendaddr[2];
    struct sockaddr_in recvaddr[2];
    int numbytes;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    int broadcast=1;
    int ret;
    const char * ip_addrs[] = {"192.168.137.255", "192.168.137.255"};
    const char * devs[] = {"eth0", "eth2"};

    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if ((sockfd[i] = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((setsockopt(sockfd[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,
                &broadcast, sizeof broadcast)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt - SO_SOCKET ");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Socket %lu created\n", i);

        // /*
        ret = setsockopt(sockfd[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, devs[i], sizeof(devs[i]));
        printf("setsockopt %lu returned %i\n", i, ret);
        if (ret==-1) {
            perror("socket");
        }
        //*/

        memset(&sendaddr[i], 0, sizeof sendaddr[i]);
        sendaddr[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
        sendaddr[i].sin_port = htons(OUTPORT);
        sendaddr[i].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.137.128");

        memset(&recvaddr[i], 0, sizeof recvaddr[i]);
        recvaddr[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
        recvaddr[i].sin_port = htons(INPORT);
        recvaddr[i].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addrs[i]);
        if (bind(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&recvaddr[i], sizeof recvaddr[i]) == -1) {
            perror("bind");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(sockfd[0]);
    close(sockfd[1]);
    exit(0);
}
```

Note that if I insert the actual NIC IPs in `ip_addrs`, outgoing packets will be correctly routed, but the socket will not receive the broadcast packets.

A proposed solution was to put a router between one device and the PC's NIC, and use NAT. This would, however, introduce latency which is not desirable here.

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain how this is a duplicate? I mentioned `SO_BINDTODEVICE` and that it's undesirable (because of privileges). Note that because I need to respond to bcast packets I cannot differentiate by IP.

Comment: If you can't use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` then I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: Why do you have two NICs on the same subnet that aren't actually connected to the same network? It seems like a broken configuration.

Comment: @Barmar it's two identical data acquisition devices whose network configuration is set in firmware. It is broken indeed. Ironically, it works under Windows, as binding the sockets to the actual IPs receives bcast packets.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into the issue of having hardcoded identical network devices to connect to one Linux box ... I used [`iptables` and `ip route` to modify outgoing packets ensuring they go to the correct NIC](http://serverfault.com/a/389004/360987) and [`tc` for stateless NAT for incoming packets](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281800/221798). The complete solution for this setup is at [the CereLink project on GitHub](https://github.com/dashesy/CereLink/issues/73#issuecomment-287924332)